# Элементы смещаются вверх flexbox Safari, что можно сделать?

Tags: html, css

Стоят все префиксы, однако все равно есть такая проблема, в других браузерах все отлично.

```css
display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
```

[image: "-15%"]

Comment: Ну и куда смотреть?

Comment: Прошу прощения, в комментарии к фото вроде писал. -15%

Comment: Нашел сейчас единственное решение и это display block и центрировать лайн хейтом и текст алайт

Comment: Во-первых, это не комментарии к фото, а его alt. Во-вторых, что -15%?

Comment: Прошу прощения, над блюдом красная плашка "-15%"

Comment: Ну и что с ней?

Comment: Заметно же, она смещена вверх, хотя должна быть по центру, и так со всеми элементы, которым даны свойства выше, и именно в сафари, что можно с этим сделать?

Comment: Ну так надо было или разметку привести, или понятно написать, что ты центрируешь текст в блоке с помощью flex'а, но в safari он встаёт выше, чем надо. А если вообще не использовать flex, а просто заменить у элемента height на line-height и добавить text-align: center?

Answer (score 0):

А может по-старинке? Ещё может оказаться, что высота элемента отличается от высоты текста на нечётное число пикселей - в таком случае рекомендую увеличить высоту на 1px.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  float: left;
  min-width: 10ch;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>-15%</div>
```